# How to auto-generate random numbers in username?

Tags: php, functions, woocommerce-offtopic, user-registration, username

I have a public-viewed community site. 
I am able to insert First & Last Name fields in WooCommerce Registration form, and auto-generate username based on the combination of First+Last Name.

But if there are two persons with the same First & Last Name, the registration will fail because of username exists if one person has registered earlier.

Can you help me with auto-generating numbers after the username if the username exists?
For example, first person is John Doe, his username will be **johndoe**.
So, if the second person with the same name registered, I want it to be, like, **johndoe1**.
If there is third person with the same name registered, that would be **johndoe2**.

Thank you in advance!

Here's my code for that auto generate username:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_new_customer_data', 'custom_new_customer_data', 10, 1 );

function custom_new_customer_data( $new_customer_data ){

// get the first and last billing names
if(isset($_POST['billing_first_name'])) $first_name = $_POST['billing_first_name'];
if(isset($_POST['billing_last_name'])) $last_name = $_POST['billing_last_name'];

// the customer billing complete name
if( ! empty($first_name) || ! empty($last_name) )
    $complete_name = $first_name . ' ' . $last_name;

// Replacing 'user_login' in the user data array, before data is inserted
if( ! empty($complete_name) )
    $new_customer_data['user_login'] = sanitize_user( preg_replace('/\s+/u', '', $complete_name) );
return $new_customer_data;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function would generate a unique user login slug:

```
function my_unique_user_slug( $slug ) {
    global $wpdb;

    $check_sql = "SELECT user_login FROM $wpdb->users WHERE user_login = %s LIMIT 1";
    if ( ! $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( $check_sql, $slug ) ) ) {
        return $slug;
    }

    $suffix = 2;
    do {
        $alt_slug = $slug . $suffix;
        $user_slug_check = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( $check_sql, $alt_slug ) );
        $suffix++;
    } while ( $user_slug_check );

    return $alt_slug;
}
```

It is based on the [`wp_unique_post_slug()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_unique_post_slug/#source) function, and you can use it like so:

```
if ( ! empty( $complete_name ) ) {
    $slug = sanitize_user( preg_replace( '/\s+/u', '', $complete_name ) );
    $new_customer_data['user_login'] = my_unique_user_slug( $slug );
}
```